# How does Amazon.com renew or buy its domain names?

Tags: amazon, domains

It's hard to believe that Amazon goes to a site like Godaddy.com to buy or renew domain names.  Do they use registrars?  If not, how do they buy & renew domains?

Comment: would you like to buy amazon.com if they accidently forget to renew :P

Comment: They are paid up through 2020 -- someone wanted to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Just curious to see how large companies manage their domain names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazon.com started out in a garage in the Seattle area in 1995.  At the time, Network Solutions was the only registrar for ".com" domains so they had to register with them.  Network Solutions is still their registrar today so they have never had to switch.  Their domain registrar can be verified in the [whois database](http://www.networksolutions.com/whois-search/amazon.com).

Many of Amazon's other domains are registered through [MarkMonitor](https://www.markmonitor.com), which is a registrar specializing in brand protection, especially for large corporations.